# Convert dynamic to static polymorphism in C++

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I need to convert a call to a function from `dynamic polymorphism` to `static polymorphism` but I'm not pretty sure on how this transformation must be done.

As first thing I have a class called Calculator that can have different implementations :

```
 template<class T>
 class Calculator {
  public:
     virtual void doSomething() = 0;
 };

 class IntCalculator : Calculator<int> {
   public:
    int data;
    void doSomething(){ ... use data .. };
 };

 class CharCalculator : Calculator<char> {
   public:
    void doSomething(){ .. };
 };
```

Then I have another class that receive as input a calculator and use it:

```
    class Matrix {
     private:
      Calculator* calc;
     public:
      void set_calculator(Calculator* calc){
        calculator = calc;
      }
    
      void run(){
       calculator->doSomething();
      }
    }
```

Now I want to convert this function call in such a way that use static polymorphism but it's not clear to me how can I do this transformation. In case of `IntCalculator` the attribute data must be loaded before passing the `calculator` to the `Matrix`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is "static polymorphism"?

Comment: @Botje https://medium.com/@kateolenya/static-polymorphism-in-c-9e1ae27a945b

Comment: I mean the one that happens at compile time.

Comment: Make Matrix a template class over the calculator type, and pass in the calculator as an argument to the constructor. Also, I am not convinced that it needs to be a pointer.

Comment: Or make `Calculator` itself follow the curiously recurring template pattern if you really want static dispatch.

Comment: @NathanPierson but if I use a solution like this:

`template<class T>
class Calculator {
 public:
    void doSomething() {
  static_cast<T*>(this)->do();
 }
};

class IntCalculator : Calculator<IntCalculator> {
  public:
   int data;
   void do(){ ... use data .. };
};

class CharCalculator : Calculator<CharCalculator> {
  public:
   void do(){ .. };
};`

How can i pass the information about type int/char?

Comment: You can give `Calculator` more than one template parameter. `template<class Numeric, class Implementation> Calculator` would let you write `class IntCalculator : public Calculator<int, IntCalculator>` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
private:
    T* calc;
public:
    void set_calculator(T* calc){ calculator = calc; }
    void run(){ calculator->doSomething(); }
};
```

Then you no longer need `Calculator` interface, and can directly use `IntCalculator`.